# Convert strings & stringsdict to gettext PO

Tags: xcode, localization, gettext, po, pootle

When localizing iOS and macOS apps, Xcode requires the use of `.strings` files and additional `.stringsdict` files (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html)) for encoding pluralization rules. I am looking for a way to combine both of these into a standard format like Gettext PO in order to import them into a translation management tool like Pootle.

`.strings` files can be converted to PO using `prop2po` from the Translate Toolkit (see [here](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/prop2po.html)). However, I am unable to find anything for including `.stringsdict`files in the conversion.

It also seems that Xcode does not include the `.stringsdict` files when exporting localization files (see [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5803908559536128)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself here. A direct conversion between `.stringsdict` and `.po` files is not possible because strings dicts support more than one pluralizable variable whereas PO files have only one single counter.